# Weird CSS background behaviour

Tags: html, css, background

I've been doing a simple project when I saw that my background is doing something quite strange and something I've never seen before. The background that I set to body tag applies only to the div inside and then repeats itself. What is even weirder is that the border that I set to body tag appears around the div element that is inside. Here's the code

```css
 *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: Helvetica;
        }
        body{
            background: linear-gradient(317deg, rgba(49,92,161,1) 0%, rgba(106,179,255,1) 100%);
            color:white;
        }
        height:100%;
        #centar h2{

            font-size:3em;
        }
        #centar{
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            margin-top:20%;
        }
        #centar input{
            width:30%;
        }
```

```html
        <div id="centar">
            <h2>Unesite dužinu prečnika:</h2>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Unesite dužinu prečnika"/>
        </div>
```

https://codepen.io/VeljkoCukic/pen/KKgaMMW

[Background error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9MHf.png)

Comment: min-height: 100%; to html

Comment: Short answer:

min-height:100vh on body.

Note that in the code you share, "height" is outside the scope of body{}